# Why doesn't my code work when I want to append something to be head of the linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
void addToHead(Node *list, Node added) 
{
    // Where NodePointer is a typedef of a pointer to a node

    (*added).next = (*list); 
    (*list) = added;        //Set list pointer back to first entry
}
```

For some reason, I'm having issues with this. Why doesn't it work? I thought adding a pointer to a pointer will allow me to change the address of a pointer (as I did with Node * list)

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what you're after because I find your question unclear.  I'm going to assume that Node contains a `Node* next` (pointer to Node) because a class or struct cannot contain a full instance of itself and therefor `Node.next` cannot be a `Node`.

First, with `(*added).next = (*list);`.   `(*list)` dereferences a `Node*` and resolves as a `Node`, so I'd be surprised if assigning a `Node*` as a `Node` would compile.

Second, with `(*list) = added;`.  This one looks more likely to compile, but it will do a shallow copy of `added` into the space pointed to by `list`.

No where in your code are you assigning an actual pointer, so I'm confused by what you mean by 'adding a pointer to a pointer'.  I also don't know what you mean by 'doesn't work'.  You need to explain what behavior you want to see, and what behavior you actually see.

Answer (score 0):

```
void addToHead(Node * list, Node* added) 
{
  //Where NodePointer is a typedef of a pointer to a node

  (*added).next = list;    //you could also do added->next = list
  list = added;      //Set list pointer back to first entry
}
```